# Modify field format in listview Django

Tags: python, django

Is there any good way that I can make modifications to individual fields of data in a list view? For example, I have a blog post model that looks like

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    document = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

and my list view looks like this:

```
class BlogPostListView(ListView):
    model = Blog
    template_name = 'blog/posts.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-create_time']
```

Obviously I want to display a list of blog posts in a table format, and I want to modify how the create_time looks (currently showing 'March 7, 2020, 10:16 a.m.', but I only want 2020-3-7 10:16); and the post document can be too long to display in a cell, I want to truncate it into only 150 words.

so what are the better ways to achieve this in a listview view?

(I read some sort-of similar questions in StackOverflow, but it is either done in the template such as reformating the time which does not solve my second requirement, or too vague to understand).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Chouvic suggested that I should use ModelSerializer, I managed to get it work in the listView. Here is my solution:

serializer:

```
class BlogListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    create_time_str = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    short_document_str = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_create_time_str(self, obj):
        return obj.create_time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")

    def get_short_document_str(self, obj):
        return obj.document[0:150]
```

as for the ListView:

```
class BlogListView(ListView):
    model = Blog
    template_name = 'blog/posts.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-create_time']
    queryset = Blog.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        posts = context['posts']
        mod_posts = BlogListSerializer(posts, many=True)

        context['posts'] = mod_posts.data

        return context
```

`BlogListSerializer(posts, many=True)` takes in posts (a list of post) and return a new list of post each with the new 'attributes' of create_time_str and short_document_str.

In the template, I just need to refer it as `<td>{{ post.create_time_str }}</td>`.

Comment: if anyone has a better and proper way, let me know, I am still uncertain what I did follow the Django's best practice.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to customise the representation between model and view. A faster way to do that is to use [serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#serializers) and `RetrieveAPIView` of DRF. Check out [installation link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/#installation). Then, you can make the use of serializer to customise representations of model's fields.

Here is pseudo code:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.generics import RetrieveAPIView

class BlogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    def get_create_time(self, blog):
        return self.create_time..strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M)

    def get_document(self, blog):
        return self.document[:151]


class BlogPostListView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Blog.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer
    template_name = 'blog/posts.html'
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, I tried this approach but encounter some errors (could be due to that I messed up other parts), couldn't' manage to get it to work in the end as I am not familiar with RetrieveAPIView. It seemed missing Meta class in the serializer as well. But I looked into the model serializer and manage to work around it in the listview. I have provided my answer below. Thanks!